# Unable to redirect Error of command

Tags: linux, shell-script

I am trying to search for a file in a directory and print a suitable message accordingly. However am not getting the required result. Eg. When the file is present in the directory the result is as expected However when no file is present the output shows like this

```
ls: cannot access 'Voucher_Sales_Order_Report_202305*.unl': No such file or directory
```

Inside Else

Although Else block is right but i want to remove the error message of ls above it.I have tried /dev/null it is still not working. Kindly help

```
#/bin/bash

cd /applogs/NFS_SO_PROCESSING
d=`date -d '1 month ago' '+%Y%m'`
filename=`ls Voucher_Sales_Order_Report_$d*.unl`

if [ "$filename" ]
then
        echo "Inside IF"
else
        echo "Inside Else"
fi
```

Comment: Please show (add to your question) exactly how the redirect is coded. It is strange to not show the one command that is not working for you. There are also better ways to test for the existence of a file.

Comment: You are getting the error because you are not redirecting anything. `ls Voucher_Sales_Order_Report_$d*.unl` will show just that if it does not exist. Redirecting standard error is done using `2>/dev/null`. So to follow along `ls Voucher_Sales_Order_Report_$d*.unl 2>/dev/null`  is what you are looking for though better approaches exist to achieve this. Also `ls` is not meant to be used in scripts

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
#! /bin/bash -
shopt -s nullglob

cd /applogs/NFS_SO_PROCESSING || exit

info() {
  [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\n' "$@"
}

die() {
  info >&2 "$@"
  exit 1
}

d=$(date -d '1 month ago' '+%Y%m')
filename=(
  Voucher_Sales_Order_Report_"$d"*.unl
)
 
case ${#filename[@]} in
  (1) info 'OK, one matching file';;
  (0) die 'ERROR, no matching file';;
  (*) die 'ERROR, more than one matching file';;
esac

do-what-you-like with "$filename", same as "${filename[0]}" in bash
```